# Prolog beginner, combining rules question?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a program thats based on these facts:

Boyle was born in 1627 and died in 1691.
Newton was born in 1642 and died in 1727.
(and so on)

I want to create a rule that determines if a person was alive during a specified year. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
scientist(boyle, 1627, 1691).
scientist(newton, 1642, 1727).
alive_after(X) :- scientist(A, B, C), B < X.
alive_before(X) :- scientist(A, B, C), C > X.
alive_during(X, Year) :- alive_after(X), alive_before(X).
```

I believe that my first two rules are correct, but they don't seem to be working as intended when I combine them for my alive_during rule. When I run my code with this as my input:

```
alive_during(1628).
X = boyle
```

It doesn't work.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog cannot unify variables that are hidden inside predicate bodies. There is no relationship between the `A` in `alive_after/1` and the `A` in `alive_before/1`. Prolog actually told you that it didn't know what you were doing when it reported these warnings: `

```
|: alive_after(X) :- scientist(A, B, C), B < X.
Warning: user://2:19:
    Singleton variables: [A,C]
|: alive_before(X) :- scientist(A, B, C), C > X.

Warning: user://2:23:
    Singleton variables: [A,B]
|: alive_during(X, Year) :- alive_after(X), alive_before(X).

Warning: user://2:27:
    Singleton variables: [Year]
```

It is **extremely important** that you read these messages as if they are **errors**, *especially* when you are new to Prolog!

The solution is to make it so that Prolog is able to unify the scientists across these predicates:

```
alive_after(Scientist, Year)  :- scientist(Scientist, Birth, _), Year > Birth.
alive_before(Scientist, Year) :- scientist(Scientist, _, Death), Year < Death.
alive_during(Scientist, Year) :- 
    alive_before(Scientist, Year), alive_after(Scientist, Year).
```

You may also find that it is a little easier to follow the logic when you give your variables meaningful names. I am guilty of using extremely terse variable names when writing very general predicates, but these are actually very specific predicates and a good name can help you understand the structure of what you're doing. It would be, I think a little harder to see how this is more correct than what you wrote:

```
alive_after(A, X)  :- scientist(A, B, _), X > B.
alive_before(A, X) :- scientist(A, _, C), X < C.
alive_during(A, X) :- alive_before(A, X), alive_after(A, X).
```

With better names, it is much easier to see why your original code is incorrect, because the scientist is not actually shared between the `alive_before/2` and `alive_after/2` calls.

Another hint that you were confused was that this response to a query makes no sense:

```
?- alive_during(1628).
X = boyle
```

Where did X come from? Variables get unified with values from the query, they do not arrive from inside predicate bodies.

An even more direct solution would be to use Prolog's built-in `between/3` predicate:

```
alive_during(Scientist, Year) :-
    scientist(Scientist, Birth, Death),
    between(Birth, Death, Year).
```

This has the added advantage that it will actually generate solutions for you:

```
?- alive_during(boyle, X).
X = 1627 ;
X = 1628 ;
X = 1629 ;
X = 1630 ;
X = 1631 ;
```

The other solution does not have this property. There are interesting predicates you can write if you do have this generating property, such as contemporaries/2:

```
contemporaries(S1, S2) :-
    alive_during(S1, Y),
    alive_during(S2, Y),
    dif(S1, S2).
```

Which generates a lot of not interesting copies of solutions, but you can get rid of them by using `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(X-Y, contemporaries(X, Y), Contemporaries).
Contemporaries = [boyle-newton, newton-boyle].
```

Comment: This really helped explain it well. Thank you.

Comment: @K.Hall Glad to help, welcome to Prolog! Don't get discouraged by this, we all start out in about this same spot.